# prove bubble sort is ordered by lemma

Tags: theory, bubble-sort, proof, isabelle, theorem-proving

I already tried to prove that fun `bubble_main` is ordered but no approach seems to work. Could someone here help me to prove the lemma `is_ordered (bubble_main L)` please.

I just delete all my previous lemmas because none seems to help *Isabelle* find a proof.
Here is my code/theory:

```
text{*check if the list is ordered ascendant*}
fun is_sorted :: "nat list ⇒ bool" where
"is_sorted (x1 # x2 # xs) = (x1 < x2 ∧ is_sorted (x2 # xs))" |
"is_sorted x = True"


fun bubble_once :: "nat list ⇒ nat list" where
"bubble_once (x1 # x2 # xs) = (if x1 < x2 
                     then x1 # bubble_once (x2 # xs) 
                     else x2 # bubble_once (x1 # xs))" |
"bubble_once xs = xs"

text{*calls fun bubble_once  *}
fun bubble_all where
"bubble_all 0 L = L"|
"bubble_all (Suc n) L = burbuja_all n (bubble_once L)"


text{*main function *}
fun bubble_main where
"bubble_main L = bubble_main (length L) L"

text{*-----prove by induction-----*}

lemma "is_sorted (bubble_main L)"
apply (induction L)
apply auto
quickcheck  
oops
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would repair your definitions. E.g., using your version
of `is_sorted` is too strict in the sense, that [0,0] is not sorted. This
is also detected by quick check.

```
fun is_sorted :: "nat list ⇒ bool" where
  "is_sorted (x1 # x2 # xs) = (x1 <= x2 ∧ is_sorted (x2 # xs))" |
  "is_sorted x = True"
```

`bubble_all` has to call itself recursively.

```
fun bubble_all where
  "bubble_all 0 L = L"|
  "bubble_all (Suc n) L = bubble_all n (bubble_once L)"
```

and `bubble_main` has to invoke `bubble_all`.

```
fun bubble_main where
  "bubble_main L = bubble_all (length L) L"
```

Then there are several auxiliary lemmas required to prove the result.
Some I listed here, others are visible in the `sorry`'s.

```
lemma length_bubble_once[simp]: "length (bubble_once L) = length L"
  by (induct rule: bubble_once.induct, auto)

lemma is_sorted_last: assumes "⋀ x. x ∈ set xs ⟹ x ≤ y"
  and "is_sorted xs"
  shows "is_sorted (xs @ [y])" sorry
```

And of course, the main algorithm is `bubble_all`, so you should prove
the property for `bubble_all`, not for `bubble_main` inductively. 
Moreover, an induction over the length of the list (or the number of iterations) 
is advantageous here, since the list is changed by `bubble_all` in the recursive call.

```
lemma bubble_all_sorted: "n ≥ length L ⟹ is_sorted (bubble_all n L)"
proof (induct n arbitrary: L)
  case (0 L) thus ?case by auto
next
  case (Suc n L)
  show ?case
  proof (cases "L = []")
    case True
    from Suc(1)[of L] True
    show ?thesis by auto
  next
    case False
    let ?BL = "bubble_once L"
    from False have "length ?BL ≠ 0" by auto
    hence "?BL ≠ []" by (cases "?BL", auto)
    hence "?BL = butlast ?BL @ [last ?BL]" by auto
    then obtain xs x where BL: "?BL = xs @ [x]" ..
    from BL have x_large: "⋀ y. y ∈ set xs ⟹ y ≤ x" sorry 
    from Suc(2) have "length ?BL ≤ Suc n" by auto    
    with BL have "length xs ≤ n" by auto
    from Suc(1)[OF this] have sorted: "is_sorted (bubble_all n xs)" .
    from x_large have id: "bubble_all n (xs @ [x]) = bubble_all n xs @ [x]" sorry
    show ?thesis unfolding bubble_all.simps BL id
    proof (rule is_sorted_last[OF x_large sorted])
      fix x
      assume "x ∈ set (bubble_all n xs)"
      thus "x ∈ set xs" sorry
    qed
  qed
qed
```

The final theorem is then easily achieved.

```
lemma "is_sorted (bubble_main L)"
  using bubble_all_sorted by simp
```

I hope, this helps a bit to see the direction what is required.

Comment: why should isabelle skip some proof's, is this because some lemmas give a erratic path to isabelle? i was trying to induct L, and skipping the fact of length. another doubt, it is neccesary to prove another lemma's to help isabelle or with the two above you mention is enough?

my aproach was trying to prove that the last element is always the biggest nat on the list. bad aproach?

Comment: Of course, Isabelle eventually won't skip proofs, `sorry` can just be used during proof development and make experiments. I inserted the various `sorry` to give you some hints on the properties you might require. And of course you have to prove that the last element is the biggest, cf. the property `x_large`.